# How to get data from different table cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, ios8.3

I have the following code which will trigger when the the didSelectRowAt is called. Which is basically when you click on any row.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if(indexPath.section == 0){
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow 
        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! addNameTableViewCell

        print(currentCell.addNameTextField.text)
    }

}
```

My problem is that I have four sections and in section zero is an button that when pressed I want to be able to return the data that is in section three.

```
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
```

So basically the problem is how to make this instead of the indexPath of the selected row, I want to be able to point it at a different indexPath.

EDIT:

```
         let indexArray = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows

        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: (indexArray?[1])!) as! addNameTableViewCell
```

I was able to solve it with the above but still be nice if a better way

Comment: let indexArray = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows

Comment: Is your tableview static cells or dynamic?, if it's dynamic you can try this
if let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! addNameTableViewCell {
   print(currentCell.addNameTextField.text)
}

Comment: Static as it wont change? I was able to solve it by looking at apple's docs and seeing that they have an function to get all the indexPaths into an array, I could just input whichever index path I want. But I can see that sometimes you can have like multiple sections or changing paths and that could be a problem. Thankfully what I'm working on isn't.